# Allow non-namespace tags in xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

Can I somehow allow html tags (or other than 'my:'-namespaced) inside the 'template' tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<my:template xmlns:my="http://my.example.com">

  <my:aa/>

  <my:aa>
    <b>stuff</b>
    <my:aa/>
  </my:aa>

  <my:bb/>
</my:template>
```

Now my schema looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://my.example.com"
        xmlns:my="http://my.example.com"
        targetNamespace="http://my.example.com"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:complexType name="MyContent">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="aa" type="MyContent"/>
    <xs:element name="bb" type="MyContent"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="template" type="MyContent"/>

</xs:schema>
```

xmllint shows up error

```
kk.xml:7: element b: Schemas validity error : Element 'b': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {http://my.example.com}aa, {http://my.example.com}bb ).
kk.xml fails to validate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference any element or complexType from another schema as long as

1. They are globally defined
2. You `import/include` those schemas/xsd
3. You reference then using correct namespace (`targetNamespace`)

If you want to use html then you really need to use `xhtml`. Find namespace details here http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/

**import tutorial**

[xsd:import tutorial](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx)

Comment: uh, so where should I put xhtml namespace to make my example work?

Comment: @spacevillain see my edit. added the tutorial for you to read

Comment: Hi Pangea, your answer is a bit too restrictive when it comes to "any element or complexType"; I would've used "any content". Also, it is incorrect to state that you strictly need import/include. You can use wildcards for specific elements/attributes in namespaces, thus allowing for those without necessarily including those schemas....

Comment: @Pangea : what should be done when only one of the elements in a xml document contains a namespace declaration(not the root element) and the rest of the elements do not contans a namespace declaration? how should the schema be written when only one of the inner elements contains a namespace?